# Angular http get from ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a rather complicated situation where I am calling data from an API that potentially has hundreds or even thousands of results. It includes options for pagination as well that I can call upon.

I need to break the list of results into pages using the API data.

The page is initially loaded with `$scope.displayData = function (url, page, limit)` and called with `$scope.displayData("linktomydata?", 1, 20);` which return something like `linktomydata?page=1&limit=20` from within my controller. This displays the records for the data fine.

However I have a directive to get the total count of possible pages based on a limit of 20 per page and I'm using a simple for loop to create a list of links beneath the data to serve as pagination. Each link is then set to call the displayData function with the relevant parameters.

```
app.directive ('paginationList', function($timeout) {
    return {
        // Set as a replaceable element
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            $timeout(function () {
                scope.$watch('pagination', function(pagination) {
                    if(pagination) {
                        for (var i = 1; i < scope.pagination.pages + 1; i++) {
                            element.append('<a href ng-click="displayData("linktomydata?", 6, 20)"></li>' + i + '</li></a>');   
                        };
                    }
                });
            })
        }
    }
});
```

This should display page 6 of the available data and still limit to 20. However the displayed data goes missing when the pagination link is clicked and nothing is returned. no console errors either.

Have I mixed up my scopes or something? Or am I just going about it all wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't `element.append('<html>')` in Angular. You do so in jQuery. In Angular, you write the HTML in the view and show/hide/generate it on condition or with ng-repeat.

Comment: You should have `ng-repeat` instead of element.append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are mixing up a little bit the different things.
That would look much better in this way:

```
app.directive ('paginationList', function($timeout) {
return {
    replace: true
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'view/paginationList.html',
    link: function(scope, element) {
        var linkToMyData = 'linktomydata?';

        //using underscore's range method is the easiest way
        $scope.range = _.range;

        scope.displayData = function(page, limit){
             //do the magic here
        }
    }
}
```

});

template:

```
<div>
    <li ng-repeat="page in range(1,pagination.pages)">
        <a href ng-click="displayData(page, 20)">
    </li>
</div>
```

usage:

```
<pagination-list></pagination-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and cleaner approach @lamisti. Apologies but I should've mentioned that scope.pagination.pages does not contain an array or object of data, but merely the value 15 where the page limit is 20 of 298 total records. Would this still work in your solution as this is why I was performing the for loop originally. Also I believe the actual functionality in scope.displayData needs to remain in the controller. Many thanks

Comment: I've updated my example aligning with your requirements. It should work in that way.

Comment: Thank you again @lamisti. After a bit of tweaking I got this working with your solution. I have to include the http://underscorejs.org/ library to get the _.range to work. Also I didn't have to use the displayData function in the directive, as it was in the controller for me to use. Took a little time but all working. Thank you again! Answer accepted :)

Comment: Cool, glad to help u